# Is it okay to heat a test tube for several minutes for evaporation of solvent inside?

Tags: equipment

I have a mixture of water and a small amount of undissolved solute in a test tube. I want to remove the water in it by evaporation method. Can the test tube carries the evaporation process with a Bunsen burner? I don't want to transfer into different glassware to avoid contamination and reduction of the solution when transferring.

Comment: "Put a test tube on fire" and "Heat a test tube" are two very different things, keep that in mind.

Comment: I think the better method would be to transfer the mixture in, say, a petri dish. You might face problems removing the undissolved stuff from the test tube later...

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

1. Heat from a Bunsen burner is pretty strong. You better make sure whatever is left after the evaporation will survive.
2. If the solvent is organic (and not super halogenated), this is a *terrible* idea because you run a serious risk of igniting your solvent vapors.